# I can not directly access an url in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, production-environment

I have a problem with a simple application. I already have it in production, but when I access a URL directly, I get an error:
In firefox:
[image]
In chrome:
[image]

But if I access localhost:8080, it is redirected to /home correctly:
[image]

I am using the following code:
In app.routes.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroeComponent } from './components/heroe/heroe.component';
import { BuscarComponent } from './components/buscar/buscar.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
    { path: 'heroe/:id', component: HeroeComponent },
    { path: 'buscar/:palabra', component: BuscarComponent },
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { APP_ROUTING } from './app.routes';

import { HeroesService } from './servicios/heroes.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroeComponent } from './components/heroe/heroe.component';
import { BuscarComponent } from './components/buscar/buscar.component';
import { HeroeTarjetaComponent } from './components/heroe-tarjeta/heroe-tarjeta.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroeComponent,
    BuscarComponent,
    HeroeTarjetaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    APP_ROUTING
  ],
  providers: [
    HeroesService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I try to change `{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }` to `{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' }` or anything and nothing, not solve.

I tried the application with the NodeJS http-server module.

Comment: Can you please provide translation or meaning of the errors you're getting?

Comment: Yes, in firefox: "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will be displayed with "junk" text in some browser settings if the document contains characters external to the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the transfer protocol or the file needs to use a byte order mark as a coding signature."
In chrome: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: ma da gusto que exista otra Mexicano por aqui :) add me on github pevargasg

Comment: All 3 screenshots have the same URL `localhost:8080/home`?

Comment: @PeS yes, but one is accessed via http get and the other through rouing from the main page

Comment: @PeS yes, is the say same that Isitar

Comment: Any solution to solve?